# Addition operation for PriorityQueue class in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, runtime-error, priority-queue, user-defined-types

I'm trying to implement a PriorityQueue in Java. I have PrinterQueue class that includes the PriorityQueue and TestPrinterQueue class for testing that. PrintJob is the type that is in this queue. The constructor is private, so I used reflection for implementing the instance of the object.

The problem occurs in runtime that I cannot add more than one objects to the queue. The size of the queue is always same. There is no compilation error. All codes are below. Thank you...

```
PrinterQueue class:

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PrinterQueue{
   private static PrinterQueue queue;
   PriorityQueue<PrintJob> pqExample;
   Comparator<PrintJob> Comparator;
   int iQueueSize = 50;

   private PrinterQueue(){
      Comparator = new Priority();
      pqExample = new PriorityQueue<PrintJob>(iQueueSize,Comparator);
  }
   public static PrinterQueue getQueue(){
      if (queue==null) queue = new PrinterQueue();
     return queue;} 

   public void addJob (PrintJob job) {
       queue = new PrinterQueue();
       queue.pqExample.add(job);
     // Use the job’s getPriority method to check its priority. PRIORITY CLASSINDA KULLANILDI.
     System.out.println("Job " + job.getName() + " is added to the printer queue" + " Size: " + queue.pqExample.size());
     Print();
  }
  public boolean isEmpty(){
      if(queue.pqExample.isEmpty())
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
  public PrintJob removeJob(){
      //TODO –remove the highest priority job from the queue
      PrintJob job = queue.pqExample.remove();
      System.out.println("Job "+ job.getName()+ "has been printed");
      return job;

  }
  public boolean isFull(){
      if (queue.pqExample.size() == iQueueSize)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
  private void Print() {

      PriorityQueue<PrintJob> pqTemp;
      pqTemp = queue.pqExample;

       while (pqTemp.size() != 0)
       {
           System.out.println(queue.pqExample.element());
           System.out.println("//");
           pqTemp.remove();
       }
  }
}
```

TestPrinterQueue class:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestPrinterQueue {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {

        Constructor<PrinterQueue> constructor = PrinterQueue.class.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[0]);
        constructor.setAccessible(true);

        PrinterQueue pqTest = constructor.newInstance(new Object[0]);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner scUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true)
        {
             PrintJob pjWillbeAdded = new PrintJob();

             System.out.println("Enter the priority:");
             pjWillbeAdded.setPriority(scUserInput.nextInt());
             System.out.println("Enter the JobName:");
             pjWillbeAdded.setName(scUserInput.next());
             System.out.println("Enter the Number of Pages in PrintJob:");
             pjWillbeAdded.setiNoPJ(scUserInput.nextInt());

             pqTest.addJob(pjWillbeAdded);

             System.out.println("**** TEST SIZE : " + pqTest.pqExample.size() + "*****");
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this information is enough to explain my problem.

Comment: Ouch, not sure where to start, but, every time you add something to the queue, you also empty it by calling Print(). That could be the reson for the constant size you're seeing.

Comment: Man, thank you very much now it works good! But still I don't understand the mechanism, because in Print function, I dont remove elements from the main queue. I remove them from the temp queue, which is equal to the other one.. I will check it again.

Comment: You are not creating a temporary queue, just another reference to the original.

Answer (score 1):

In your addJob() method, you're assigning queue to a new PrinterQueue object each time. Changing this to "queue = getQueue()" should fix that.

Comment: Thanks, I excatly did that but it does not work. The size is still same.. Trying to figure it out..

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I found the mistake that occurs in different place. It is reasoned by Print function.